# How can I delete an element of a multidimensional array that contains a specific index?

Tags: php

In the following array, which I have stored in `$_SESSION['doc_brick_array']`, I am trying to find the element with `brick0`. I want to delete this element, and then re-index the outer array. How can I do this?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [brick0] => Array
                (
                    [city_name] => Lahore
                    [clinic_name] => shifa hospital
                    [attendant_name] => ali
                    [drd1_cell1] => 03017666454
                    [mbv] => 666
                    [brick_name] => LHR-0002
                    [clinic_address] => i-8 markaz
                    [drd1_phone] => 9798797
                    [drd1_cell2] => 04037777888
                    [drd1_email] => abc@yahoo.com
                    [visit_time] => m
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [brick1] => Array
                (
                    [city_name] => Rawalpindi
                    [clinic_name] => aljanat hospital
                    [attendant_name] => kanzal
                    [drd1_cell1] => 03014544567
                    [mbv] => 6000
                    [brick_name] => 
                    [clinic_address] => i-9 markaz
                    [drd1_phone] => 07337837
                    [drd1_cell2] => 03017767575
                    [drd1_email] => abcd@yahoo.com
                    [visit_time] => m
                )

        )

)
```

**The code I have tried**

```
for($g=0; $g<=count($_SESSION['doc_brick_array']); $g++){
    if (($key = array_search($brick_code, $_SESSION['doc_brick_array'][$g])) !== false) {   
        unset($_SESSION['doc_brick_array'][$key]);  
        $_SESSION['doc_brick_array'] = array_values($_SESSION['doc_brick_array']);
    }   
}
```

Comment: what are you asking?

Comment: So nobody wastes time... You've shown us what you have. What is it that you want? "reindex it" could mean many different things.

Comment: You have to copy the subarray first and then unset it... `$_SESSION['newindex']=$_SESSION['oldindex'];` !!THEN!! `unset($_SESSION['oldindex'];`

Comment: If you mean "re-index" as in change "brick1" to "brick0", then you'll need a prepositional indexer like [`Haldayne\Boost\Map::rekey()`](http://haldayne.github.io/documentation/api/classes/Haldayne.Boost.Map.html#method_rekey)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are after here is [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) which, from the PHP.net site

> array_values() returns all the values from the array and indexes the
>   array numerically.

As an example:

```
$a = array(1 => 'one', 2 => 'two', 3 => 'three');
unset($a[2]);
/* will produce an array that would have been defined as
   $a = array(1 => 'one', 3 => 'three');
   and NOT
   $a = array(1 => 'one', 2 =>'three');
*/

$b = array_values($a);
// Now $b is array(0 => 'one', 1 =>'three')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter` to remove any elements from `$_SESSION['doc_brick_array']` that have a `brick0` key.

```
$x = array_filter($_SESSION['doc_brick_array']), function($y) {
         return !isset($y['brick0']);
     });
```

Then use `array_values` to reindex the result.

```
$_SESSION['doc_brick_array']) = array_values($x);
```